# Get account name from AccountSettingsPane in UWP app

Tags: authentication, uwp, windows-10-universal, c++-cx

I'm using AccountSettingsPane + WebAccountProvider UWP API to display the list of currently connected accounts in Windows (see picture). Is there any way to get the account display name (in this case: awkoren@gmail.com) using an instance of WebAccountProvider which you get as a parameter in WebAccountProviderCommandInvokedHandler? I tried everything and there seems to be no way to do this (except of having an instance of WebAccount class, but that requires authentication first) - am I missing something obvious? I mean, the AccountSettingsPane *knows* how to display that name, after all.

[image]

Comment: Display name is belong to personal profile data that need authentication to get. I don't think it can be got without authentication.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT But AccountsSettingsPane somehow gets it prior to actual authentication (by "actual authentication" I mean getting a token to access some resource). So clearly that name is stored somewere

Comment: When you get a `WebAccountProvider`, can you look in the WebAccountProvider's `User` property?
There are functions on that to get the account picture and the associated user properties.